# Is there a way to force the initial load of a figure?

Tags: python, plotly

Using Python/Plotly, I'm trying to create a figure that has a map and a slider to choose the year. Depeding on the year that is selected in the slider, the map should render different results.

Evertyhing is working fine with exception for one thing - I cannot set the initial load state of the map to be the same as the initial step as defined in

`sliders = [dict(active=0, pad={"t": 1}, steps=steps)]`

When the first render is done, and the slider has not yet been used, the data displayed seems to be accordingly to the last state of the `data_slider` list, ie. it shows the last values that were loaded in the list (I'm not totally sure about this conclusion).

Is there a way to set the first data display accordingly to the step that is pre-defined? Or in alternative, a way to force the first load to be something like `data_slider[0]`.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import random

ds = 'https://archive.org/download/globalterrorismdb_0718dist/globalterrorismdb_0718dist.csv'
# ds = os.getcwd() + '\globalterrorismdb_0718dist.csv'

fields = ['eventid', 'iyear', 'country', 'country_txt', 'region_txt', 'city', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'nkill']

df = pd.read_csv(ds, encoding='ISO-8859-1', usecols=fields)

df = df.loc[df['iyear'] >= 2000]

df['nkill'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

df = df.groupby(['country_txt', 'iyear'])['nkill'].sum().reset_index()
df = df.loc[df['nkill'] > 0]

data_slider = []

for year in df.iyear.unique():
    df_year = df[(df['iyear'] == year)]

    data_year = dict(
        type='choropleth',
        name='',
        colorscale='amp',
        locations=df_year['country_txt'],
        z=df_year['nkill'],
        zmax=15000,
        zmin=0,
        locationmode='country names',
        colorbar=dict(
            len=0.5,
            thickness=10,
            title=dict(
                text='Number of fatalities',
                font=dict(
                    family='Arial',
                    size=14,
                ),
                side='right'
            ),
            tickfont=dict(
                family='Arial',
                size=12),
        )
    )

    data_slider.append(data_year)

steps = []

for i in range(len(data_slider)):
    step = dict(
        method='restyle',
        args=['visible', [False] * len(data_slider)],
        label=(format(i + 2000))
    )

    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(active=0, pad={"t": 1}, steps=steps)]

layout = dict(
    geo=dict(
        scope='world',
        showcountries=True,
        projection=dict(
            type='equirectangular'
        ),
        showland=True,
        landcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        showlakes=False,
        showrivers=False,
        showocean=True,
        oceancolor='white',
    ),
    sliders=sliders
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data_slider, layout=layout)

fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(family='Arial', size=12),
    autosize=False,
    width=1250,
    height=750,
    margin=dict(
        l=25,
        r=0,
        b=100,
        t=50,
        pad=0,
    )
)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    # html.H1(children='Test2'),

    # html.Div(children='''
    #     Example of html Container
    # '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='fig',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: When I try to download the file from the URL you provided ( https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/pedrombnevoa/dv/master/globalterrorismdb_0718dist.csv), I get a 404 error.

Comment: Fixed it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not on  `sliders` but on the traces you are defining in `data_slider`. You need to play with the `visible` parameter in order to have the first plot properly rendered. The following trick should work.

```py
data_slider = []

for i, year in enumerate(df.iyear.unique()):
    df_year = df[(df['iyear'] == year)]

    data_year = dict(
        type='choropleth',
        name='',
        colorscale='amp',
        locations=df_year['country_txt'],
        z=df_year['nkill'],
        zmax=15000,
        zmin=0,
        locationmode='country names',
        visible= True if i==0 else False,
        colorbar=dict(
            len=0.5,
            thickness=10,
            title=dict(
                text='Number of fatalities',
                font=dict(
                    family='Arial',
                    size=14,
                ),
                side='right'
            ),
            tickfont=dict(
                family='Arial',
                size=12),
        )
    )

    data_slider.append(data_year)
```

**Extra**

Given that you are generating all the plots outside the `app` you could actually avoid to use `dash`.